# Update con Inner join

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

estoy tratando de actualizar un atributo "grupo" de mi tabla proceso, hago la relacion con la tabla subproceso el cual tiene como referencia el idProceso de la tabla proceso, pero me marca un error al momento de ejecutar la consulta.

```
UPDATE P set P.grupo="" FROM proceso P INNER JOIN subproceso SP 
ON P.idProceso=SP.idProceso where P.idUnidadNegocio=3
```

Comment: que error te marca?

Comment: checa si así te sirve mira UPDATE table_name as P 
INNER JOIN subproceso as SP ON P.idProceso=SP.idProceso
set P.grupo=""
where P.idUnidadNegocio=3

Comment: Me marcaba un error de sintaxis, creo que la sintaxis que usé es para sql server, pero estaba usandando mysql. Sí asi lo solucione Alfredo, gracias.

Comment: Listo, gracias amigo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te anexo la siguiente respuesta

```
UPDATE table_name as P INNER JOIN subproceso as SP ON 
P.idProceso=SP.idProceso set P.grupo="" where P.idUnidadNegocio=3
```

Donde lo importante fue quitar el `FROM` y además ligar el alias `P` con el nombre de la tabla que le corresponde.

Answer (score 0):

Creería que el objeto de la actualización es poner en "" el grupo cuya unidad de negocio es tres y que el numero de proceso este en la tabla de subprocesos, si es correcto puedes hacer: 

`UPDATE set grupo="" FROM proceso WHERE 
P.idUnidadNegocio=3 AND 
idProceso IN (SELECT idproceso FROM subproceso)`

Answer (score 0):

Esta consulta tambien trabajo para mi:

```
use BASEDEDATOS;
UPDATE `BASEDEDATOS`.`user` u
INNER JOIN `TABLE_1` ccu ON (ccu.user_id = u.id)
INNER JOIN  `TABLE_2` ccr ON (ccr.id = ccu.construction_id)
SET u.date = '2020/10/10'
WHERE ccr.id = 33 AND fecha_altura < '2020/10/10';
```

Comment: Considera explicar tu código